# Nutch 1.11 crawl Issue

Tags: solr, nutch

I have followed the tutorial and configured nutch to run on Windows 7 using Cygwin and i'm using Solr 5.4.0 to index the data

But nutch 1.11 is having problem in executing a crawl.

**Crawl Command**
$ bin/crawl -i -D solr.server.url=http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr /urls /TestCrawl 2

**Error/Exception**

Injecting seed URLs /apache-nutch-1.11/bin/nutch inject /TestCrawl/crawldb /urls
    Injector: starting at 2016-01-19 17:11:06
    Injector: crawlDb: /TestCrawl/crawldb
    Injector: urlDir: /urls
    Injector: Converting injected urls to crawl db entries.
    Injector: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1012)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:445)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:418)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:650)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:739)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:722)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:633)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:421)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:281)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:125)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1282)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1282)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:833)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.inject(Injector.java:323)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.run(Injector.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.main(Injector.java:369)

```
Error running:
/home/apache-nutch-1.11/bin/nutch inject /TestCrawl/crawldb /urls
Failed with exit value 127.
```

Comment: And what is your question? Take a look at [this help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about asking. You should provide some more details instead of just dumping some error and some commands.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Will rephrase my question :)

Answer (score 1):

I can see there are multiple problems with your command, try this:

```
bin/crawl -i -Dsolr.server.url=http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/core_name path_to_seed crawl 2
```

The first problem is that there is a space when you pass the solr parameter. The second problem is that the solr url should include the core name as well.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry!!  I'm new to Nutch and Solr. Can you please tell me what is core name?

Comment: Just use collection1

Comment: To be honest, this doesn't even work. The -Dsolr is rejected by the script in version 1.13 (and pretty sure in 1.11 also). In addition, the error remains if the script is passed that way. Do you know any specific version of solr that should be used?

Answer (score 0):

> `hadoop-core` jar file is needed when you are working with nutch

- with nutch 1.11 compatible hadoop-core jar is 0.20.0
- > please download jar from this link :
  >   http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhadoop0200corejar.htm
- > paste that jar into `"C:\cygwin64\home\apache-nutch-1.11\lib"` folder and it will run
  >   successfully.